# Fade screen on sleep and brighten on wake

Tags: suspend, screen

I'm looking for a way to control the screen brightness from code. I saw this post but this just turns the screen on and off. How can I dim the screen before it goes to sleep instead of just turning it off and wake up the screen in code (later using I/O) by brightening it gradually?

Comment: How many seconds delay would you like for fading before suspend and brightening during resume? The shorter delay the quicker the monitor fades/brightens but  shorter you wait for suspend and resume to complete.

Comment: I would like the whole process to take about 2-3 seconds to fade and to brighten. I just to make the going to sleep better looking and the awakening better looking than just ON->BLACK or Black->ON

Comment: I think it can be done. During suspend use `xrandr` software brightness to step down 100% to 0% over 3 seconds at 33 times per second with 1% increments. Problem is during 1 of those 100 frames, brightness will be black as set by Ubuntu. Reverse would be true during resume. So I'm not sure if it's worth it...

Comment: A caveat is what happens if suspend crashes (which happens a lot)? The screen would have faded to black and you can't see anything making it look like a Black Screen of Death when really there is something on the screen. A program would have to restore the screen so the user can read it. That said it's a novel idea and challenging so I'm looking at incorporating it into eyesome: https://github.com/WinEunuuchs2Unix/eyesome